# What is the key binding to switch consoles in gnome

Tags: linux, gnome

I see the system configuration allow workspace switch, but there is no console switch. What I mean is, when I open multiple consoles in the desktop view, what are the keys to switch among them? My console is konsole.

Answer (score 0):

If its different windows it is alt+tab, if its different tabs then its generally ctrl+pagedown or ctrl+pageup